# Using jQuery to toggle menu visibility

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I have a code for a navigation page I'm working on, to be used on the tumblr platform. The navigation is basically set up like so, with #navstart being the category of the navigation items and #navitem used for individual items. Below is a snippet of how I formatted it.

```
<div class="navstart" style="display: inline"><img src="http://s28.postimg.org/fsjo9bo7x/themes.jpg"></div>
<div class="navitem" style="display: inline">
    <a href="/tagged/my%20themes"><img src="http://s7.postimg.org/y3jld46m3/mythemestile.jpg">
    <a href="/tagged/main%20page"><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/80fdvp0mv/mainpagethemes.jpg">
    <a href="/tagged/char%20page"><img src="http://s23.postimg.org/4lsf45izf/musepagethemes.jpg">
    <a href="/tagged/nav%20page"><img src="http://s9.postimg.org/ilwgc60r3/navigationpagethemes.jpg">
```

I'm trying to make it to where all #navitem divs are hidden until I click on the #navstart div that the #navitem falls under, which will make all the navitems in that category show up. How can I do this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ / http://api.jquery.com/show/. Eg `$('.navstart').on('click', function() { $(this).next('.navitem').show() })`. Just start your `.navitem` as `display: none` in CSS

Comment: I suggest a few changes.  `) Use <ul> + <li> instead of <div>, 2), next your child menus within the parent item's <li>, 3) Use pure CSS to open/close your menus.  See how Bootstrap menus work: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default .... and the CSS here: http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css (Search for ".navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu")

Answer (score 0):

As in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/57t3xuwn/1/) how to make use of `.toggle()` to achieve the show()/hide toggling in jQuery

Also as Steven suggested, implementing it with a set of `<ul>` and `<li>` is a good habit.

```js
$('.toggle-nav').on('click', function () {
    $('.inner', this).toggle();
});
```

```css
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.toggle-nav>span {
    cursor:pointer;
    width:120px;
    height:20px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#555;
    color:#EEE;
    padding:5px 10px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.inner {
    list-style-type:none;
    display:none;
}
.inner .item {
    height:50px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    border-bottom:1px dashed #999;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-nav"> <span>Click to Toggle!</span>

    <ul class="inner">
        <li class="item">One</li>
        <li class="item">Two</li>
        <li class="item">Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Firstly the CSS for hiding the submenu:

```
.navitem {
    display: none;
}
```

2.Remove `display: inline;` from navitem - change `<div class="navitem" style="display: inline">` with `<div class="navitem">`.

2.After that include the jQuery library:

3.And finally include this script in your page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navstart').click(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('.navitem').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
        } else {
            $('.navitem').fadeIn();
        };

        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```